# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices in COM

Tags: azure, com, interop

I created a library for interacting with WindowsAzure.MobileServices

```
[ProgId("MyPush.ClientLib")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("********-****-****-****-************")] 

[ComVisible(true)]
public class ClientLib
{
    private static MobileServiceClient MobileService;

    private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable;

    public ClientLib()
    {
        /*
        MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
          "https://galpush.azure-mobile.net/",
          "*******************************");

        todoTable = MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
        */
    }
```

i used regasm to register my library but when i try to init new MobileServiceClient
i have error 80070002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you also deploy the references with your library:

- Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.8)
- Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.1.3)
- Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.2.15)

Comment: thank you. I need a project.exe.config for my project.exe which is connected to my COM object. I renamed the file MyPush.dll.config to project.exe.config